# Java (spymemcached) and PHP (memcached)

Tags: java, php, memcached

I'm trying to build a Java app that will set data in Memcached and have a PHP script to get the same data later in the process. So far, I haven't been able to find a way to get a 100% hit rate. To make sure nothing was wrong with the SETs, I manually confirmed the data was added to Memcached. Based on [Consistent hashing in PHP and Java](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?9,192006), I tried to use KETAMA (see code below) without any success.

Configurations:
- Spymemcached (2.8.1)
- PHP (5.3.10) 
- PECL/memcached (2.0.1)
- libmemcached (1.0.4)

What would be the best strategy to share data between Java and PHP? Is there a configuration I'm not using correctly? Should I be using another library?

Thank you for your help!

---

```
MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient
(ConnectionFactory) new ConnectionFactoryBuilder ()
.setProtocol (Protocol.TEXT)
.setHashAlg (DefaultHashAlgorithm.KETAMA_HASH)
.setFailureMode (FailureMode.Redistribute)
.setLocatorType (Locator.CONSISTENT).build(),
AddrUtil.getAddresses("192.168.0.101:11211 192.168.0.102:11211"));
```

---

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addserver('192.168.0.101', 11211);
$memcached->addserver('192.168.0.102', 11211);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION ,Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
```

Comment: For my tests, I used "test_1" to "test_1000"

Comment: and u are saying that php client and java client returning you different values for a key?

Comment: PHP will just return "false" as it's not able to find the value based on given key. It works for 30% of the GETs but I assume it's just because I only have two servers and it could luckily be querying from right server.

Comment: are u sure u are using the same hash algorithm for both clients?

Comment: I tried with: PHP > Memcached::HASH_FNV1A_32 and Java > DefaultHashAlgorithm.FNV1A_32_HASH. I also tried with PHP > Memcached::HASH_FNV1A_64 and Java > DefaultHashAlgorithm.FNV1A_64_HASH. I finally tried with PHP > Memcached::HASH_CRC and Java > DefaultHashAlgorithm.CRC_HASH.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13757/discussion-between-fretre-and-darthvader)

Answer (score 0):

In spymemcached there's a reported [issue](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/issues/detail?id=118&can=1&colspec=stars%20id%20Milestone%20Priority%20Status%20Summary) with KETAMA hashing algorithm. It refers to version 2.5rc1 but it seems that this still occurs.

Try another java memcached client: [xmemcached](https://code.google.com/p/xmemcached/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, still not able to get this to work with xmemcached.

Comment: Unfortunately xmemcached also uses different string to calculate hash than libmemcached. The good new is that xmemcached has LibmemcachedMemcachedSessionLocator so just try it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are thinking about doing the same thing, there's a better strategy. Twitter provided [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) (nutcracker), a fast and light-weight proxy for memcached. Using that, I don't have to worry if Java and PHP are using the same hashing algo, the proxy takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. After many hours of investigation, I found that this is because of the different `flags` defined in PHP and Java memecached clients.

I used [xmemcached](https://code.google.com/p/xmemcached/) to make it work.

Firstly, create a new `StringTranscoder` to decode the response, ignoring the flags definition and convert all of them to `String`

```
/**
 *
 * Php memcached extension uses flags=0 or 1 for all SET values, the default StringTranscoder in Xmemcached uses 0 for string
 *
 */
class PhpStringTranscoder extends PrimitiveTypeTranscoder<String> {

    private String charset = BaseSerializingTranscoder.DEFAULT_CHARSET;

    public PhpStringTranscoder(String charset) {
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    public PhpStringTranscoder() {
        this(BaseSerializingTranscoder.DEFAULT_CHARSET);
    }

    public String decode(CachedData d) {
            String rv = null;
            try {
                if (d.getData() != null) {
                    rv = new String(d.getData(), this.charset);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return rv;
    }

    public static final int STRING_FLAG = 1;

    public CachedData encode(String o) {
        byte[] b;
        try {
            b = o.getBytes(this.charset);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return new CachedData(STRING_FLAG, b);
    }

}
```

Finally, use this new `PhpStringTranscoder` to create session:

```
    MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(String.format("%s:%s",address,portNum));
    builder.setCommandFactory(new TextCommandFactory());
    builder.setTranscoder(new PhpStringTranscoder());
    builder.setSessionLocator(new LibmemcachedMemcachedSessionLocator(100, HashAlgorithm.ONE_AT_A_TIME));
    MemcachedClient memcachedClient = builder.build();
```

`memcachedClient` is the one you should use.